# Stop Google Drive File Stream from Immediately syncing a deleted file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I noticed that anytime a file is put into the Google Drive File Stream folder the entire file is uploaded even if it is deleted from the user's computer mid-sync. Is there a way to change that behavior? Or even stop it from uploading mid-sync? I've tried going into the cache folder (%AppData%\Local\Google\DriveFS) but had no luck finding anything there.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Signing out did the trick for me. I got a prompt saying:

> Sign out of Drive File Stream? There are 2 files (600.0GB) that have not yet been uploaded to Google Drive. If you sign out, these files, as well as files marked "Available offline," will be removed from this computer.

Only drawback is that it sounds like you may need to re-download any files that you want to be available offline.

Backstory:
I tried to upload a couple 300GB files and they (understandably) hung. I deleted the files on my computer but drive still continued trying to upload them. Every time I restarted my computer or Drive File Stream they would show up as pending or syncing.